# Displaying the database nodes from Firebase in a list in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Link to my Database Structure]

A simple question:

Referring to my database image, I want to get the values of the children of node "user" in a list in an Activity, i.e. values "a" and "m" should be displayed in the list.

What should I use and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");
yourRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    List<String> usersList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        String userName = (String) ds.getKey();
        usersList.add(userName);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
  }
});
```

This is the way in which you'll have in your list, `a`, `m` ans so on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to display these list items in ListView or a kind of realtime View or RecyclerView but don't get the desired result.

Comment: Forceclosing app

Comment: Ok, but for sure you have an error in your log_cat. Which is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the info from the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

```
List<User> allUsers = new ArrayList<>();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user");

ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    allUsers.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        allUsers.add(userSnapshot.getValue(User.class));
    }
    yourRecyclerViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    // Getting Users failed, log a message
    Log.w(TAG, "loadUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    // ...
  }
});
```

Comment: I want to display these list items in ListView or a kind of realtime View or RecyclerView but don't get the desired result.